# Answered and Modified

Tags: discussion

I answer a question, it should be answered, but why it shows modified? Is it because I modifiy my own answer ?

I though modified simply mean edit the user question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

[image]

Comment: Yes.  It is normal when you browse questions in the tag-specific list view.  The list is ordered by the last-change date, whomever made the change to the Q+A gets "credited".  It never made much sense to me personally, I prefer seeing the question owner, but nobody ever complained about it afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered the question after that you might've edited your answer which resulted in modified status from what I know.